# Can't set color for UIBarButtonSystemItem

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have been trying to have a UIBarButtonSystemItem in my toolbar and it always defaults to the standard blue. If I create it with an image or title it works fine with the correct color, try it with UIBarButtonSystemItem and it goes to the default color and nothing I have found on the internet works.

heres the code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *overlays = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl target:self action:@selector(overlays)];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the default color"? Are you trying to change the color, and if so, how?

Comment: The standard grey/blue of the icons. Im trying to change the color to something else. I can do this with my own images on buttons or segment controls but it doesn't work with the system ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to create my own button. Seems to be a bit of a bug that initWithBarButtonSystemItem default back to the standard colour. Few people have requested to Apple to fix it but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but the color of the button is dependent on the color of the navigationbar. You must create a custom button like you did. This is most likely a Apple HIG deal.